# Browser not sending back cookies, but curl does

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am developing a nodejs application from scratch. I am just beginning to play with node. I am building a login system, but I found an issue:

When I login with correct name and password, a cookie is set with a 'remember_token' value. It is supposed to store the user session. This are the cookies in my google chrome browser

[image: remember token cookie]

The cookie is set correctly, but when the browser makes a new request, the cookie value is not set in the server:

[image: no remember token]

when I make a request trhoug curl, cookies are recieved by the server:

```
curl -i 'http://localhost' -b "remember_token=ZnVuY3Rpb24gbm93KCkgeyBbbmF0aXZlIGNvZGVdIH0wLjA1NTg2MzU1MTU2MjY1MTk5"
```

[image: remember token when curl]

**Aditional info**

I added this lines to app.js before any middleware is called:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('\nrequest: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
  next();
});
```

and this is the output when I make a request from the browser:

```
request: {"host":"node","connection":"close","cache-control":"max-age=0","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36","referer":"http://localhost/","accept-encoding":"gzip,deflate,sdch","accept-language":"es-419,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-AU;q=0.4,en-CA;q=0.2,en-US;q=0.2,en-NZ;q=0.2,en-GB;q=0.2,en-ZA;q=0.2","cookie":"connect.sid=s%3AB8g0VGivuIuOt4A9DKl3WMFu.625Hfc6W4TiMUJyK4X9clfeNa0Fi8Pd%2Fdmg0sSPAW5E","if-none-match":"\"-651269513\""}
```

No remember token cookie on the header. Tested in: google chrome, chromium and mozilla firefox. Why is this?

**Update**

This is how I create my cookies:

```
exports.identificar = function (req, res, success, fail) {
    var remember_token = null;
    var u;

    usuarios.findByEmail(req.body.sesion.email,function(usuario){
        if (usuario) {
            crypt.comparePassword(req.body.sesion.password, usuario.password_digest, function(err, resp) {
                if (err) {
                    fail('Hubo un error de encripción');
                } else if (resp) {
                    remember_token = usuario.remember_token;

                    u = usuario.toJSON();

                        delete u['password_digest'];
                        delete u['remember_token'];
                        delete u['fecha_token'];
                        delete u['token'];

                    if (typeof req.body.sesion.recordar !== "undefined"){
                        res.cookie('remember_token', remember_token, {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), secure: true});   
                    } else {
                        res.cookie('remember_token', remember_token, {secure: true});
                    }
                    req.session.usuario = u;
                    success(u);
                } else {
                    fail('Contraseña incorrecta');
                }
            });
        } else {
            fail('Usuario no encontrado');
        }
    });
};
```

**SOLVED**

I finally solved it by removing the "secure:true" option in the server when I set the cookie, but. Why did it happen?

Comment: How are you setting the cookies? Could you post some code?

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving the cookie in the browser? Did you check the headers in the `FireBug`?

Comment: In express you set the cookies using `res.cookie()`. See http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: The cookies are set correctly, The first image I posted is an screenshoot from google chrome cookies configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secure option is for secure connections, I had to remove the "secure:true" flag on the server when I set the cookie.